# 2sxc Allow changes after formula filled a value

Tags: 2sxc

I'm trying to create a field that automatically fills a date (or whatever value).
The formula works but it also locks the value from any changes the user attempts.

I've tryed this:

```
v1(data, context) {
  return new Date();
}
```

and this:

```
v1(data, context) {
  if (context.cache.alreadyRun) return new Date();
  context.cache.alreadyRun = true;
}
```

but the value always gets locked in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is wrong. Once it has run, it shouldn't return the date any more, but just continue with the existing value.
It should be more like this:

```js
v1(data, context) {
  if (context.cache.alreadyRun) return data.value;
  context.cache.alreadyRun = true;
  return new Date();
}
```

Note that I believe it's still wrong - you probably just want to set the date when it's empty, and not set it again every time the form is opened. So this is probably what you're looking for:

```js
v1(data, context) {
  if (data.value) return data.value;
  return new Date();
}
```